# Textbox in reactjs unable to input text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

The percise error I'm getting (when I start to type in textbox) in my log is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.setTextFilter is not a function
at ExpListFilters._this.onTextChanged (ExpListFilters.js:17)
```

Here is my function:

```
onTextChanged = (e) => {
        this.props.setTextFilter(e.target.value);
    };
```

Rendered inside component:

```
<div className="in-group__item search-box">
<input placeholder="Search for your expenses" 
className="text-input" 
type="text" 
value={this.props.filters.text} 
onChange={this.onTextChanged}/>
</div>
```

Also using redux to map state to props by passing down filters from actions.

```
import { setTextFilter } from '../actions/filters'
```

Redux:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
        filters: state.filters
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't using mapDispatchToProps while exporting the component (using connect), see below.

**Previous**

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ExpListFilters);
```

**Updated**

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ExpListFilters);
```